# Word motions ignore `n` in `\n`

Tags: vim

Consider the following line of Python:

```
print("\nHello, world!")
```

To change the word `Hello` to `Hola` one might like to simply `ciw`. However that naive command replaces the `n` of `\n` as well. How might one configure VIM to ignore the leading character of a word if immediately preceding the word is found the character `\`?

Note that VIM highlighting does recognize the leading `n` as belonging to the `\n`, so perhaps a solution could be based off of this.

Answer (score 3):

The word motions in Vim are universal (or "naive", as you say), and are only controlled by the `'iskeyword'` setting. That's usually a good thing, because they have proved to be applicable to all sorts of text, and most programming languages.

What you want is a specialized text object; you could implement such by remapping the default `iw` text object (and probably also the related motions like `w`, `e`, etc. for consistency). I haven't seen any such implementation, but it's definitely doable in Vimscript. The [textobj-user plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) might help.

Alternatively, you can apply the text object first on visual mode, and then correct the selection for the leading `n` character: `viwolc`. The `o` goes to the other side of the selection, `l` reduced it by once, and finally `c`hange the selection.

...or just re-type the deleted `n`; after all, it's just one character and quick to do. That's what I would probably do.